# Find item by ANY

Tags: c#, linq

I want to assign value of prompt.message whose prompt code is '2041'. I have put the if check but I don't know how to get that prompt item's message.

**Class structure**

```
public class Prompts
{
    public List<Prompt> prompt { get; set; }
}

public class Prompt
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set; }
}
```

Tried this so far:

```
if(Prompts.prompt.Any(p => p.code == 2041))
{
    string message = Prompts.prompt[0].message;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should rather use [`FirstOrDefault()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482(v=vs.110).aspx) in this case. `Any` will just return a boolean value.

```
var message = Prompts.prompt.FirstOrDefault(p => p.code == 2041)?.message;
```

would give you null when it's not found or the message for the first one in C# 6

In case you don't use C# 6 yet, a similar way would be

```
var prompt = Prompts.prompt.FirstOrDefault(p => p.code == 2041);
string message;

if (prompt != null) {
    message = prompt.message;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the first item satisfying a given condition use `First`:

```
string message = Prompts.First(p => p.code == 2041).message;
```

If you might not have any such items, use `FirstOrDefault` so it doesn't throw (it will return `null` if the item isn't found).

If you have *multiple* items satisfying the condition use `Where` to get them all. `Any` isn't all that useful here.

Comment: Your code will throw a `NullReferenceException` if there's no matching item when it tries to access the `message` property if you use `FirstOrDefault`. Icepickle's answer does the same, but uses null-conditional operator (`?.`) to avoid that.

Comment: @AndersonPimentel Actually the first example will through an `InvalidOperation` I believe (no matching item found). I note that in the next line. I agree `FirstOrDefault` is nearly always better.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems.  One is that you don't have a code property on your Prompt class.  Second is that calling "Any" just lets you know that there exists an object that meets the criteria.  Use "Where" to actually find those objects.

```
public class Prompts
{
    public List<Prompt> prompt { get; set; }
}

public class Prompt
{
    public string message { get; set; }
    public int code { get; set;}
} 

....
var promptsWeCareAbout = Prompts.prompt.Where(p => p.code == 2041);
if(promptsWeCareAbout.Any()) 
{
    string message = promptsWeCareAbout.First().message;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
     List<Prompt> promptList = new List<Propmt>();
    promList = db.Prompts.ToList();    
    string Message = prompList.Where( p => p.Code == 2041).FirstOrDefault().Message;
```